# Can I re edit the post once it got rejected?

Tags: support

Let's say I edit a post; before it gets approved, the user who wrote the post owner makes minor changes, and my suggested edit gets rejected by the Community user. (It happened me a couple of times.)

Can I re-edit those posts if there is still the need to edit them?

Answer (score 1):

You can suggest an edit for the same post, even if the first one was rejected. The only time you cannot suggest further edits is when X of your past suggested edits were all rejected; in this case, you cannot anymore suggest edits for any post.

Comment: Also, rejections by Community does not count. Users are not punished if their edits are rejected by race condition.